# Confirm() method for Windows UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, cordova, uwp

I am working on an application using Cordova and at some point I need to show a confirm box and I use the `confirm()` method for android and it works. However, it does not work on the Universal Windows platform (UWP).

I have tried using a c# method called `MessageDialog()` and invoking it into the JavaScript and it works perfectly. However, it's an asynchronous method i.e. it does not block the following lines of code. I also tried`ContentDialog()` but it crashes the app

Can someone help me by explaining how to use `ContentDialog` or suggesting another JavaScript or c# methods that I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs)

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`

And use `navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, [title], [buttonLabels])`

- message: Dialog message. (String)
- confirmCallback: Callback to invoke with index of button pressed (1, 2, or 3) or when the dialog is dismissed without a button press (0). (Function)
- title: Dialog title. (String) (Optional, defaults to Confirm)
- buttonLabels: Array of strings specifying button labels. (Array) (Optional, defaults to [OK,Cancel])

Full example:

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!', // message
     onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',           // title
    ['Restart','Exit']     // buttonLabels
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;    
....

public async void DisplayDialog(string title, string message)
{
    ContentDialog SaveData = new ContentDialog
       {
            Title = title,
            Content = message,
            CloseButtonText = "Ok"
       };
           ContentDialogResult result = await SaveData.ShowAsync();
 }
```

Try this, this code works for me.

Thanks